# Azure Active Directory ASP.NET Core 3.1 "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." Are we missing any configurations?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

We are using .NET core 3.1, Azure AD , and Visual Studio Connected Services templates which attempt to generate the startup.cs file.

Are we not setting something in the config?  We are not using client secret, but maybe that's the problem?  Connected Services did generate one.

**Startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
            });



            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //The new UseEndpoints method
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {             
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**AppSettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "macrowhq.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AppIDURL": "https://xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/WebApplication11",
    "ConfigView": "MVC"
  }
}
```

**Launch Settings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61517",
      "sslPort": 44363
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44363/weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication11": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**500 on sign-in oidc**
[image]

**We saw the login screen for our domain**

The error  "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." only happened after we entered the userid/password (yes we are sure it was correct.)

The odd thing is that the user account does show signed in despite this message.

[image]

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44363/signin-oidc
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: [::1]:44363
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
date: Fri, 06 Mar 2020 21:56:30 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 500
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
:authority: localhost:44363
:method: POST
:path: /signin-oidc
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 1681
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8Lp55qWi8TlPh0rBkxAxUdnRkP-8BQvFEB24nS5JppFP4F8...
        .AspNetCore.Correlation.AzureADOpenID.SGSLll-jiFohbpdZx0poFsgBfko79OWPcNnHcA7gEXs=N...
        .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8Lp55qWi8TlPh0rBkxAxUdnofEIcTW_vXX1wIOPuDZ5u_dF...
        .AspNetCore.Correlation.AzureADOpenID.2eJUPEWi45vkhK12OGyyEGfTVDnHQj-ydAmkECan5ZE=N...
        .AspNetCore.AzureADCookie=CfDJ8Lp55qWi8TlPh0rBkxAxUdlMAHAFXphv1Kp9khZBbtL5kMZf6lLLU...

origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
id_token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkhsQzBSMTJza3hOWjFXKdKmhGqmuL0CnCHYkt8QtFdlCQfsjGeQZ...
state: CfDJ8Lp55qWi8TlPh0rBkxAxUdnJ07dNioFne0krEAmVmwXBA-5pCOswFvE6Kt0oIPcckWGfljAPW3b8XnTXCY5-dGLhxrS8fI0A...
session_state: b4d30d59-0e31-4645-9876-e002bd1c7...
```

Comment: What is your content of the error message details in your application’s 500 response?

Comment: I attached content of the 500 above.

Comment: You posted the HTTP Request headers, not the response error message.

Comment: Need the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no examples now for Core 3.1 Web API which we use for an Angular/Web API solution. Here's how to get it to work.

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

namespace Core31API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";


            });
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Properties/launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:45978",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Core31API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The WeatherForeCast.cs controler...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Core31API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The first time you activate the application you will be prompted to login, then asked to grant permissions. Click yes to everything and you should see the weather forecast response.

If you trace the network exchange after the sign in to your domain with proper userid/password. You should see this exchange in the Browser.

[image: cookie exchange]

The set is to set the cookie, 
The sign-in-oidc is a redirect which is asking the server to redirect to the secure SSL port 443.

*The Wireshark Trace*

[image: tls]

Notice that all TLS packet exchange is to the SSL port of 443 on the local computer. This prevents hackers from seeing the exchange from the browser, you have to run Wireshark to see it. Most companies don't allow Wireshark installations for non-devs.

NOTE: Even though this worked from the Backend we were unable to get the frontend to use this Web.API endpoint.  [I've asked this question for that issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695920/angular-asp-net-core-3-1-azure-ad-how-to-authenticate-frontend)

Answer (score 2):

Please pay attention to your middleware order . Modify :

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

To :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

So that authentication middleware will handle the AAD response and authenticate user .